# What is the default bean scope used by Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot

I can't find this information anywhere. 
Can someone explain how spring boot 'decides' what the right scope is?
Are the beans all singletons?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Spring Boot doesn't decide anything about the bean scope, this is plain Spring framework functionality. Default bean scope is singleton scope (meaning, one instance of that bean in the application).

Comment: I'd +1 that if you would rename _application_ scope by _singleton_ scope (and the typo; I assumes you meant one instance per application)

Comment: Yes, what i wanted to say is, that singleton scope in Spring is different from the singleton pattern (i.e. you can have two bean definitions for the same class, which results in two singleton beans). There are several questions on SO about that confusion.

Comment: Agreed, but why don't you use "meaning, one instance of that bean in the container"

Answer (score 6):

Here is the official documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes

Default scope for a Spring Bean in singleton.

Comment: That link is broken.